# Regex string matching python issue

Tags: python, regex

i am trying to learn how to use regular expression in order to filter strings, especially i am trying to filter the following string:

> some text \n {{Information \n | region = [[Western]] \n | image  = image187a.jpg{{!}} \n| .... \n }} \n some text

What i would like to do is to extract only the portion of string that is included between *"{{Information"* and *"}}"*, also between the two delimiter tags may appear other closing curly brackets.
I wrote the following piece of python code but it does not work at all.

```
print re.split(r'^\{\{(Information) \}\}$', information.string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Something like this https://regex101.com/r/pZ3lG8/1`^.*\{\{(.*)}}`

Comment: result = re.search('\s*\{\s*\{\s*(Information\s*[^}]*)\}\}', 'YOUR INPUT STRING') result.group(0)

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the text inside the Information "Tag":

```
import re
text = "some text \n {{Information \n | region = [[Western]] \n | .... \n }} \n some text"
result = re.search(r'{{Information (.*)}}', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(result.groups()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a lazy quantifier between the delimiters so that it can match additional characters that span multiple lines. Adding multi-line mode is making it so that `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the same line. Remove that. A useful mode though would be dot-all.

```
re.search('{{Information .*?}}', information.string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vI9eJ4/2)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using re.search() to re.split() for this, as you are trying to search for a pattern. You might try something like this:

```
import re

some_text = 'some text \n {{Information \n | region = [[Western]] \n | .... \n }} \n some text'

rx_match = re.search(r'{{Information(?P<info>.*?)}}', some_text, re.DOTALL)

if rx_match is not None:
    print rx_match.group('info')
```

The `(?P<name>...)` is a bit more advanced. It's a named group, and it allows you to pick the information out by name. A more simple way to do this would be:

```
rx_match =  re.search(r'{{Information(.*?)}}', some_text, re.DOTALL)

if rx_match is not None:
    print rx_match.group(1)
```

For the regex, the `{` don't need to be escaped. The `[^}]+` is a negative character set. (The `^` inverts the characters to match). It says to match one or more characters which are not `}`s.

You would then need to confirm that the match was successful. If so, then you you can use the `.group()` method to extract the data for the `()` groups.

As a matter of my opinion, Python may not be the best language to learn regex in, but it does handle it. It may be best to learn and test your regex elsewhere, and then use them in Python, until you get the hang of them.

Comment: The reason `{{` and `}}` are used as delimiters is because it has low likelihood of being needed within the contained string. If you use `[^}]+` to capture up until the delimiter, it won't work if the string contained any single closing curly braces. E.g. this would fail `{{Information test={hi} region=[[Western]]}}`

Comment: I have noticed that my string may contain closing curly braces inside the two delimiters tags (like in the example of @4castle).

Comment: Okay. Knowing this, you would need to change the regex a big. There are two changes I would make. First, I would add `re.DOTALL` (also called `re.S`) because you have newlines which are separating the pattern. Also, somebody mentioned lazy quantifiers. I don't think it makes a difference for the text you've given, but it should be helpful. So, I am editing the regex from `re.search(r'{{(?P<info>[^}]+)}}', some_text)` to `re.search(r'{{Information(?P<info>.*?)}}', some_text, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: The lazy quantifier keeps the `.*` from capturing past the delimiter and capturing the `}}` of a later match. To see what I mean, look at [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dC2eP2/1) of what can happen without the `?`